# What is the best image file format to convert past images and "standardize"?

Tags: php, python, image

I have a huge repository of .png, .tiff, .jpeg and other image file formats.

My requirement is to

1. Convert them to a single file format without significant image quality loss when viewed normally (images are not zoomed)
2. Images are mainly photographs, some have large text fonts.
3. Images must be all-browser compatible

Disk Space is not an issue

Comment: What did you try so far in terms of of your goal to accomplish?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? i.e. Why are you trying to avoid multiple formats?

Comment: @BraveNewCurrency My App requires users to upload images, I'm trying to keep them/covert to one file format

Comment: It's not the case that you have to store a JPEG on your webserver if you wish to serve JPEGs to clients. It's perfectly possible, sensible and easy to store say, a TIF, yet serve a JPEG derived from it with GD or ImageMagick. I would think long and hard before discarding a whole load of image quality and metadata in some unnecessary quest for compatibility or uniformity.

Comment: @MarkSetchell True, but wont reading from an image and then delivering the bits in a converted format on runtime give a significant computation overhead?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm building this app to scale for a large number of users, would you recommend using GD/ImageMagick with a long TTL cache? The CDN would be doing most of the caching in my case

Answer (score 1):

Each of the popular file formats is popular for its specific strengths, so it depends on which qualities are most important to you. I'll address each of your requirements (but in a different order):

3. All-browser compatible: this limits the field to GIF, JPEG and PNG (see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization#selecting-the-right-image-format). Most newer browsers support a few additional formats, if you can limit yourself to those browsers. The link has some good guidelines for choosing formats.
4. Photographs: GIF only supports a 256 colour palette, so it will degrade a photograph considerably, this is not a plausible option.
5. Minimal loss of quality: PNG loses no quality, JPEG loses some due to its compression technique. Since you are not concerned about disk space at all, PNG is better.

Regarding size, PNG will be <del>about double the size of</del> somewhat to quite a lot larger than JPEG for photographs. But if you're keeping a higher resolution for your JPEGs to offset the loss of quality from compression, you can lose some of that size advantage.

Comment: PNG will actually be more like 10x-100x the size of a JPEG.

Comment: Fair enough, the "double the size" comment was a bit rash, even for a ballpark. I converted some 12-Mpixel photos from a digital camera from JPEG to PNG and they came out 2-4x larger. But image compression is a complex topic and the size of a JPEG is quite variable depending on the makeup of the photo, the compression level set, and even the software doing the compression. So it's better to say that JPEG will be somewhat to quite a lot smaller than PNG.

Answer (score 0):

.png if you need transparency.

.jpeg if you don't need trransparency.

.tiff is a bad choice. It is not widely supported by browsers.